# Tikz sqrt function not plotting sqrt(0)

Tags: tikz-pgf, sqrt

I am trying to plot a function involving `sqrt` but I don't understand why it is not plotting until sqrt(0).

The blue curve should reach y=0 at x=8 but it stops before, which does not happen with the red curve. Does someone know how to force the blue curve to plot on the full domain between x=0 and x=8?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
    scale only axis, % To ensure same size on all pictures axis
    restrict y to domain=-12:12,
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    ticks = none,
    samples=150]

    \addplot [no markers] coordinates {(12,10)}; % To maintain scale at size without ticks

    % Plot curves
    \addplot[blue, very thick, domain=0:8]{sqrt(20/2.8*(8-x))};
    \addplot[red, very thick, domain=0:9.5]{sqrt(20/2.8*(11-x))-1.3};
    \addplot[red, very thick] coordinates {(9.5,0) (9.5,1.98)};

    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the case that a vertical line with `\addplot coordinates ....` causes problems. The reason why the blue plot is not complete is that there are rounding errors. It suffices to wrap the argument of the square root in `abs`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
    scale only axis, % To ensure same size on all pictures axis
    restrict y to domain=-12:12,
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    ticks = none,
    samples=150]

    \addplot [no markers] coordinates {(12,10)}; % To maintain scale at size without ticks

    % Plot curves
    \addplot[blue, very thick, domain=0:8]{sqrt(abs(20/2.8*(8-x)))};
    \addplot[red, very thick, domain=0:9.5]{sqrt(20/2.8*(11-x))-1.3};
    \addplot[red, very thick] coordinates {(9.5,0) (9.5,1.98)};

    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution works to complete the blue curve (you wrote red in your answer). I accepted your answer.

Comment: @JuCa You are right, that is a typo. Thanks! BTW, if you use `xmax=12,ymax=10,`, you can drop `\addplot [no markers] coordinates {(12,10)};`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple plot for the vertical line segment instead. The slope of a vertical line is `±inf` which can cause problems with pgfplots.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
    scale only axis, % To ensure same size on all pictures axis
    restrict y to domain=-12:12,
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    %ticks = none,
    samples=150]

    \addplot [no markers] coordinates {(12,10)}; % To maintain scale at size without ticks

    % Plot curves
    \addplot[blue, very thick, domain=0:8]{sqrt(20/2.8*(8-x))};
    \addplot[red, very thick, domain=0:9.5]{sqrt(20/2.8*(11-x))-1.3};
    %\addplot[red, very thick] coordinates {(9.5,0) (9.5,1.98)};
    \draw [red, very thick](9.5,0) -- (9.5,1.98);

    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Another option to increase the accuracy is to increase the number of samples, as a plus, your curve will look better.

`\addplot[blue, very thick, samples=1000, domain=0:8,]{sqrt(20/2.8*(8-x))};`

[image]

Comment: I have not understood the question...but I like your answer.

Comment: Thanks for being very supportive ;-)

Comment: Thank you but this does not solve my problem. It only hides it by changing the red curve which is here only to show the problem. Outside of the minimum example, I need the blue curve to be plotted entirely, not stopped before sqrt(0).
For clarification, I would need your axis to be plotted until the origin at (0,0).

Comment: OK, I added another option to correct the problem and make the curve much better.

Comment: Insufficient number of samples makes the curve looks like line segments at the vicinity of (8,0).